# fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: dockerfile, ros2

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUddg.png)

I have attached the screenshot of an error which I am facing.

I am trying to build a docker image for an Autoware.Universe application with ROS2 Galactic for Ubuntu 20.04 as a base image. But facing this above error at the last step while building Autoware.

It says tf2_geometry_msgs package is missing, and I have already included this package in my docker file using `RUN apt-get install -y ros-galactic-tf2-geometry-msgs` command, but gives same error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this above error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. Then I checked the /opt/ros/galactic/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/. It didn't contain tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp, then I download the tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp and put it in the file. The problem was solved. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

`tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp` is missing in Galactic because it was added in Humble.

- https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Humble-Hawksbill-Complete-Changelog.html#tf2-geometry-msgs
- https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/418